# How to install tig docs via Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, tig

I installed `tig` via `Homebrew` and `tig` works okay, but is there are way to also cleanly install its `man` pages via `brew` too instead of from source (i.e. avoiding `make install-doc` as described at https://github.com/jonas/tig/blob/master/INSTALL.adoc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you installed Homebrew with standard install directories, i.e.
>   relatives to /opt/homebrew, there are 2 commands to register the
>   binaries and man files to be used:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/sudo -s
> echo /opt/homebrew/bin >/etc/paths.d/homebrew
> echo /opt/homebrew/share/man >/etc/manpaths.d/homebrew
> exit
> ```
>
> If you are using bash or zsh as your actual shell, you will have to
>   enter one simple command to take into account these 2 environment
>   modifications:
>
> ```
> . /etc/profile
> ```
>
> If you want to learn more how these 2 directories are used under MacOS
>   X, read:
>
> ```
> man path_helper
> ```
>
> -- [daniel Azuelos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/22003/daniel-azuelos)